# Don't understand why the bounds are different for two similar questions

Tags: probability, integration, proof-explanation

This question comes from MIT CRW 6.041.

I don't understand why are the integral bounds for $x$ different. I take $1\le x \le y \le 2$ to mean that $1\le x \le y$ and $x\le y \le 2$, but because of transitivity $1\le x \le 2$, so the $\int^2_{x=1}$ in $1(a)$ makes sense.

But then why is the integral in $1(b)$ $\int^y_1$ instead? What changed that forces us to evaluate the upper bound as $y$ instead of $2$?

I know this is rather basic, but I literally haven't touched maths in almost a decade, so I really can't figure this out. Could anyone help please?

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that x \leq y. So, after fixing an x, vary y such that the inequality $1 \leq x \leq y \leq 2$ is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region can be defined by the inequalities $1 \leq x \leq y \leq 2$. When you write the limits of integration for such a region, you can put either variable on the inside or outside. On the outside, the limits of integration go through the entire range of the variable; in this particular problem, these wind up being $1$ and $2$ either way, but that's specific to this problem.

On the inside, you need the range of the inner variable for a given value of the outer variable. Here, if the inner variable is $y$, then $x$ is fixed in the inner integral, so you have $x \leq y \leq 2$. If the inner variable is $x$, then $y$ is fixed, so you have $1 \leq x \leq y$.

Finally, the second problem *has* to be done with $x$ on the inside, because to get $f_Y(y)$ you need to remove the dependence on $x$, which means you need to fix $y$ and integrate with respect to $x$.

When I have taught this subject in the past, I have emphasized thinking of the inner integral in terms of the endpoints of an arbitrary slice with the outer variable held fixed. Thus, if you are integrating $dx dy$, then the inner limits are the left and right endpoints of a horizontal segment through the region ($y$ is constant on horizontal lines). If you are integrating $dy dx$, then the inner limits are the bottom and top endpoints of a vertical segment through the region ($x$ is constant on vertical lines). If you draw the picture, you will see that for this triangle, the diagonal is on the *bottom* of a vertical line and the *right* of a horizontal line, which is why the variable limit doesn't show up in the same spot.

Comment: Thank you so much! So just to confirm my understanding is correct, in the case of $\int^2_1(\int^2_{y=x} ax dy)dx$, because $x$ is the outer variable, it goes through the entire range of the variable, whereas $y$ as the inner variable must have $x$ fixed, so $y$ only goes from $x$ to $2$. Likewise for $\int^y_1 ax dx$ because $x$ is the only one being integrated, it is treated as an inner variable thus having $y$ fixed, and so $x$ goes only from $1$ to $y$. Is this right?

Comment: Sorry I have one small question: if it says $1 \le x \le 2$ and $0\le y \le x$ instead, does this mean we do $\int^2_0 \int^x_0 ax dy dx$ and $\int^2_1 ax dx$ instead?

Comment: @DanielMak 1. You have that right, yes. 2. That also looks right.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Together with usual drawing and mentioned by @Ian arbitrary slice method, I always am thinking about formal verification i.e. proving set equality:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{1}
    \space1\leqslant x \leqslant 2 \\
    0 \leqslant y \leqslant x
  \end{array}\right\} = \left\{ \begin{array}{1}
    \space 1 \leqslant y \leqslant 2 \\
    y \leqslant x \leqslant 2
  \end{array}\right\} 
$$
Generally for formal reasoning one should consider formal definitions of domain, for example
$$
  U(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{1}
    \space a \leqslant x \leqslant b \\
    \phi_1(x) \leqslant y \leqslant \phi_2(x)
  \end{array}\right\}
$$
and try to get from here
$$
  V(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{1}
    \space c \leqslant y \leqslant d \\
    \psi_1(y) \leqslant x \leqslant \psi_2(y)
  \end{array}\right\} 
$$
From first set it's easy to see, for example, that $c=\inf_{x \in [a,b]} \phi_1(x)$ and $d=\sup_{x \in [a,b]} \phi_2(x)$. But to solve inequalities i.e. reverse functions can be tricky.
Exactly here helps sketch, as first set possibly need to be divide in some subsets, for example, on which $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are monotonic and where formal solve of inequalities gives unique result.